# How to know when a TreeView Node is closed ( not Expanded)

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qt-quick

I found in the doc [TreeView doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html) that you can use `onExpanded` to know when a `Node` from a `TreeView` is `expanded` but how can you know when a `Node` is `closed` ?

Code example:

```
TreeView {
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 300
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Permissions"
        role: "filePermissions"
        width: 100
    }
    model: fileSystemModel

    onExpanded {
       console.log("expanded :" + index)
    }
}
```

Comment: [`onCollapsed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#collapsed-signal)?

Comment: You are right, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#collapsed-signal), `onCollapsed` is the opposite of `onExpanded`, so you can check when that signal is emitted.